# Can't create term for product attribute

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, customization, terms

Please help. I need to create product attribute term after I create a product attribute taxonomy.

```
wc_create_attribute([
  'name' => 'Size',
  'slug' => 'size'
]);

// This will only work If I refresh the page
wp_insert_term( 'Large', 'pa_sizeee' );
```